# jQuery Cycle plugin advanced slider

Tags: jquery, slideshow, cycle

I want to build a slideshow with the jQuery Cycle plugin, I've done it before but now I want an advanced slider.
The slider needs to scrollUp and fadeOut with an delay between the fadeOut and the scrollUp from the next slide;

This is my code sofar

```
$.fn.cycle.transitions.customSlide = function($cont, $slides, opts) {
 opts.fxFn = function(curr, next, opts, after) {
  $(curr).hide(function() {
   $(next).delay(opts.delayBetween).show(function() {
    after();              
   });
  });
 };
};

$('#slideshow2').cycle({
 fx: "customSlide",
 delay: 3500,
 timeout: 2000,
 delayBetween: 1000
});
```

The code above should just show and hide the object; how can I make it work so it slides up, and fades out?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you wanted this specifically in the custom function but here is a version just using the built in cycle properties.  The animOut is where the magic happens to provide the slideUp and fadeOut functionality.  Hope this helps.

```
    $('#slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'custom',
        cssBefore: {  
                left: 0,  
                top:  0,  
                width: 0,  
                height: 0,  
                opacity: 1, 
                display: 'block' 
        }, 
        animOut: {  
                opacity: 0,
                top: -50
        }, 
        animIn: {  
                left: 0,  
                top: 0,  
                width: 200,  
                height: 200  
        }, 
        cssAfter: {  
                zIndex: 0 
        }, 
        delay: -3000 
    });
```

Comment: Hi Josh, thank you for your comment. This is not exactly what i am looking for. The animation is correct although i'm looking for a method to pause between the slides.